# How do I describe this software tool?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Imagine you have 100 files stored across your computer, and you need to add a certain piece of text in 20 of them.

A software tool helps you do this by providing filter criteria, which helps you arrive at the 20 necessary files. From within the tool, you can open each one from it's location so that you can add the necessary text.

The tool does not add the text for you, so we can't call it a bulk text addition tool. It does, however, simplify the process by removing the necessity of navigating to each relevant file and opening it in order to add the text.

What would the correct term/phrase be to describe such a tool?

Comment: In macOS, this tool is called Finder.

Comment: _Search, Finder_, etc.

Comment: Whatever the tool calls itself.

Comment: Free text search and edit tool